# Unable to understand this Banach Space example

Tags: functional-analysis

The notion of a "Banach space" seems simple. My textbook says it is a normed vector space that is also complete. Normed, Okay. Vector Space, Okay. Complete, Okay.

An example that was given is $R^n$ with norm $||x|| = |x|$

Now I am confused...What does it mean by "with"?

Suppose I have a function on $R^2$, $sin(x)$. I take the norm/abs value of it which gives me $|sin(x)|$, I do not see anything magical with this process. Does it mean that $|sin(x)|$ belongs to Banach space but $sin(x)$ does not? This is very confusing, can someone help explain?

Comment: It means that every Cauchy sequence of the Banach space converges to an element of the Banach space in the given norm (completeness).

Comment: The completeness does not mean we have $\| \sin(x) \|$ in our Banach space. Completeness means that with respect to our norm $\| \cdot \|$, all Cauchy sequences of elements of our Banach space converge to some element of our Banach space. So let $B$ be your Banach space and $\| \cdot \|$ your norm, and let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $B$. Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $n,m \geq N$ we have $\|f_n - f_m\| < \varepsilon$ - this is where the norm comes into play.

Comment: hi vaultboy, can you provide an explicit example as what a ($f_n$) sequence would look like?

Answer (score 1):

A Banacha space $X$ has a norm, or is provided **with** a norm, ussually denoted by something like $\|\ \|$. You can think of $\|x\|$ as the size of $x$ in $X$. Since there may be different norms, one says: "Let $X$ be such and such space with norm $\|\ \|$ defined as ..."

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space consisting of vectors $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, not of functions. Neither $\sin x$ nor $|\sin x|$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can provide $\mathbb{R}^n$ with many norms. The one that your text denotes by $|x|$ is probably the Euclidean norm
$$
|x|=|(x_1,\dots,x_n)|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\dots+|x_n|^2}.
$$
This means that you measure the size of a vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ by that expression. Other usual norms are
$$\begin{align}
\|x\|_1&=|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|\\
\|x\|_\infty&=\max(|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|)
\end{align}$$